# Как создавать нестандартный интерфейс?

Tags: winapi, интерфейс, c++

Photoshop cs5:[image]

Сразу видно много нестандартных элементов управления, которых нет в Windows.
Как сделать такую строку меню, такие панели с кнопками и т.д.? Придётся ли создавать свои классы элементов управления?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, вам придётся создавать собственный класс контрола. Ну или воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками (которые, в свою очередь, уже создали такой класс для вас).

Если вы не боитесь английского, вот [ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk2h3c6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) на Майкрософтовскую документацию.

---

Дополнение: [вот](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/mfc/1003370.flat), кажется, неплохое описание на русском.